# $this->value = $dbarray returns nothing

Tags: php, html, mysql, function, class

So I am trying to learn about class and function etc, and im stuck on trying to return value from MySQL.

php code:

```
<?php 
    class SQL{
             var $value

    function GetMYSQL_SERVER(){
        mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root',''); 
        mysql_select_db('admin');
          $q = "SELECT * FROM `configurations` WHERE `Information` = 'MYSQL_SERVER'";
          $result = mysql_query($q);
          $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
          $this->value = $dbarray['Value'];
        }       
    };
    $MYSQL = new SQL;
    ?>
```

HTML code:

```
<?php include "include/process.php"; ?>

<td>Mysql Servername</td>
<td><input type="text" style="width:100px;"></td>
<td><?php echo $MYSQL->value; ?></td>
```

So the problem appears when I execute the HTML code. 
It returns blank on the HTML server value.

Comment: Missing semi-colon at the end of `var $value` ?

Comment: Also i don't think there is something called `var $value` .

Comment: Turn error reporting on and up

Comment: Just so you know - `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated and it might be in your best interest to start coding using the `mysqli_*` functions. you can read more about it here [PHP News](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetMYSQL_SERVER()` never called, so:

1. Rename it to `__construct()` - it will be called automatically on `$MYSQL = new SQL;`

or

1. Manually call `GetMYSQL_SERVER()` method after `$MYSQL = new SQL;` like `$MYSQL->GetMYSQL_SERVER();`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the query to something generic just to show the concept...

```
<?php   
class SQL{
   var $value; 
   public function GetMYSQL_SERVER()
   {
      mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');  
      mysql_select_db('admin');
      $q = "select 'value' as Value";
      $result = mysql_query($q);
      $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      $this->value = $dbarray['Value'];
  }       
};


$MYSQL = new SQL();

/// you have to call the function 
$MYSQL->GetMYSQL_SERVER(); 
?> 

<!-- ?php include "include/process.php"; ?-->

<td>Mysql Servername</td>
<td><input type="text" style="width:100px;"></td>
<td><?php echo $MYSQL->value; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling your method that sets the `value` property:

```
$MYSQL = new SQL;
$MYSQL->GetMYSQL_SERVER()
```